# Why is the `cron.hourly` line in `/etc/crontab` the only one without `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron`?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab

I haven't changed my `/etc/crontab`, yet. It's still the default content, which is also the default content for many Linux distros:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Why is the `cron.hourly` line the only one without `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron`? Why isn't there a `cron.hourly` in `anacrontab`, too?

---

**Update:**

As @Giacomo1968 commented, the answer to "What exactly does `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron` do?" can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/etc-crontab-what-does-test-x-stand-for for example. But the main question still stands: why does the procedure for `cron.hourly` differ from the other lines?

Comment: `-x` checks for executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the smallest period that [Anacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron) is designed to work over is daily, so it can't be used to manage hourly cron jobs.

Anacron is designed to handle a very specific use case, namely making sure that infrequently run cron jobs still get run on systems that aren't always powered on. Realistically, there's almost nothing that both needs to be run hourly, *and* needs to be run immediately if an hourly run was missed. Given this, the developers of Anacron decided to allow for significantly simpler (and also more reliable) code that doesn't pay attention to the time previous tasks ran, just the date they ran. In turn, this means that Anacron is designed to operate in terms of days, not hours or minutes like most cron implementations do, and therefore it can't be used for handling hourly jobs.

In reality, Anacron doesn't actually do any scheduling itself either, which is why those entries in your `/etc/crontab` are there, without those, anacron won't run (or might only run on startup), so they're there to make sure it runs even if the system is on for a long time.

As far as hourly jobs in general, you will likely find `/etc/cron.hourly` to be empty on your system. Most of the classical uses for that (or even more frequent cron jobs) were cases where you were making sure something was up-to-date, or checking the state of some piece of hardware or software via polling. Both use cases are better served by using event-driven models instead of polling models, and thus have generally been migrated to such designs.